# How do I contribute bindings for media keys on my not yet supported system?

Tags: keyboard, media-buttons, contributing

I recently bought a Sony Vaio VGC-M1 for very, very cheap, but found some things simply wouldn't function on their own due to lacking support of this system. The five special keys at the top of the keyboard is one of those things that wouldn't function. (They're brightness down/up, mute, volume down/up in that order)

After some fiddling about with commands like showkey and setkeycodes, I managed to actually make them work properly. Now I wish to contribute these changes back to the community, but where/how do I begin? Where does Ubuntu get its other media keys support from? What project should I go to in order to have these keys work forever for everyone who happens to have a system like this?

(For the interested: I use a little script on boot that does the following:)

`setkeycodes e01b 114
setkeycodes e01e 115
setkeycodes e01f 113
setkeycodes e026 224
setkeycodes e027 225`